# ASP.NET Session_End parameters?

Tags: asp.net

Session_End in Global.asax in Asp.net has sender and eventargs parameters.  Is there any documentation on what these parameters contain for Session_End?

Comment: Why do you want to know? What are you going to do with the answers?

Comment: @CodeCaster Some identification on what user/ip or something that lost the session.

Comment: Hmm.  According to the docs it is supposed to be Session_OnEnd which is the event handler while Session_End, ends the session.

Comment: What have you tried? Why don't you debug it and check the types of sender and eventargs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the source of the [`HttpApplicationFactory` class](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/HttpApplicationFactory.cs):

It doesn't matter whether the handler method is called `Session_End` or `Session_OnEnd`, both are handled the same and raised through `HttpApplication.EndSession(..., object eventSource, EventArgs eventArgs)`, which is called from classes in `System.Web.SessionState`.

The `eventSource` will be the class raising the event and the `EventArgs` will be either `EventArgs.Empty` or some internal object containing session data.

But all of this is [undocumented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178583.aspx), so I had to stop digging as you shouldn't rely on it.

Answer (score 3):

No. Not as far as I can find.

In fact it can be anything of course, but [the source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/State/SessionStateModule.cs,bae4ce87317e675c) tells us what is really raised:

```
 HttpApplicationFactory.EndSession(sessionState, this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

The actual call is done [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpApplication.cs,1449).

The `sender` is the session state. The eventargs is set to `EventArgs.Empty`. (`this` is used as object here the event is raised on)